# git clone command is not working?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am trying to clone bit bucket repo. Once I execute the following command after installing git I am facing following issue :

```
$ git clone https://usernam@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git
Error :fatal: unable to access'https://username@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git/': 
Failed to connect to hostname port 8000: Connection refused
```

How can I get past this error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An https url should attempt to contact the port 443.

If it tries to contact 8000, that might indicate an intermediate proxy: check `git config -l|grep -i proxy`, or your environment variable (`env or set|grep -i proxy`)

You can also try a `curl -L -v https://usernam@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git` to have more information.

Finally, don't forget to try and clone through ssh if https does not want to work: see "[Set up SSH for Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html)", and `git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git`.

Comment: @vimalmishra still, I would love to know why git tries to contact the port 8000 when using https... No proxy? Firewall of any kind?

Comment: I don't know ,Couldn't figure out what was the issue.will update you once I figure out.Still working on!!

Comment: I think I had some proxy setting under env.After removing those it worked with git clone as well @VonC

Answer (score 1):

Modify your url to use git or ssh protocol for transfer.

e.g.
git clone https://github.com/abcd/bashScripts.git

becomes:

**git clone git@github.com:abcd/bashScripts.git**